# Count values from array over particular number and return occurrence

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array as below:

```
$array1 = array
   (
   array(1, "Harry", "Male", 30),
   array(2, "Troy", "Male", 4),
   array(3, "Vicky", "Female", 22),
   );
```

I want to return how many times the 4th "column" is over the fixed number of 10

So for example, I'm chasing the following:

```
MalesUnder10 = 
MalesOver10 = 
FemalesUnder10 = 
MalesOver10 =
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_filter` to filter the array. Use `count` to count the result

```
$array1 = array (
   array(1, "Harry", "Male", 30),
   array(2, "Troy", "Male", 4),
   array(3, "Vicky", "Female", 22),
);


$MalesUnder10 = count(array_filter( $array1, function( $o ){
    return $o[2] == "Male" && $o[3] < 10;
}));

$MalesOver10 = count(array_filter( $array1, function( $o ){
    return $o[2] == "Male" && $o[3] > 10;
}));

$FemalesUnder10 = count(array_filter( $array1, function( $o ){
    return $o[2] == "Female" && $o[3] < 10;
}));

$FemalesOver10 = count(array_filter( $array1, function( $o ){
    return $o[2] == "Female" && $o[3] > 10;
}));
```

This will result to:

```
$MalesUnder10 = 1
$MalesOver10 = 1
$FemalesUnder10 = 0
$FemalesOver10 = 1
```

---

**Note:** People with age 10 does not count on the logic. You can change it by `$o[3] => 10` or `$o[3] =< 10`

---

Here is a [live Demo](http://www.3v4l.org/dBN16). Thanks to Nick

Comment: Was just making a demo of this very code for my answer, so you may as well add it to yours. https://3v4l.org/dBN16

Comment: Thanks mate! Spot on!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to count those variables with a simple counter and `foreach`:

```
$array1 = array
    (
    array(1, "Harry", "Male", 30),
    array(2, "Troy", "Male", 4),
    array(3, "Vicky", "Female", 22),
    array(3, "Sharon", "Female", 9),
);

$MalesUnder10 = $MalesOver10 = $FemalesUnder10 = $FemalesOver10 = 0;

foreach ($array1 as $arr) {
    switch ($arr[3]) {
        case $arr[3] > 10:
            if ($arr[2] === "Male") {
                $MalesOver10++;
            } else {
                $FemalesOver10++;
            }
            break;
        default:
            if ($arr[2] === "Female") {
                $MalesUnder10++;
            } else {
                $FemalesUnder10++;
            }
            break;
    }

}

var_dump("Number of Males Under 10 is " . $MalesUnder10);
var_dump("Number of Males Over 10 is " . $MalesOver10);
var_dump("Number of Females Under 10 is " . $FemalesUnder10);
var_dump("Number of Females Over 10 is " . $FemalesOver10);
```

#### Output

```
string(29) "Number of Males Under 10 is 1"
string(28) "Number of Males Over 10 is 1"
string(31) "Number of Females Under 10 is 1"
string(30) "Number of Females Over 10 is 1"
```